# how to properly use quotes in javascript

Tags: php, javascript

I am using a bit of JavaScript like this:

```
echo '<a href="javascript:playSong'."('$row[artist]','$row[title]','$row[sourcefile]')".'">';
```

My problem is that sometimes my `$row[artist]` and `$row[title]` variables contain double qoutes.

When this happens it breaks the `javascript:playSong();` function call.

For example if the line was output like this:

`<a href="javascript:playSong('Danny Elfman','Beetlejuice Theme (Kamei Halloween Edit)','2009-10-31-10-52-01.4521.data','28330')">`

Everything would be fine.

But sometimes the function will look like this:

`<a href="javascript:playSong('Danny Elfman','Beetlejuice "Theme" (Kamei Halloween Edit)','2009-10-31-10-52-01.4521.data','28330')">`

Which would then cause my site to think the command ends at the double quote before "Theme" and thus cause it to fail.

Is there a way I should be properly quoting my javascript so it treats double quotes inside the function as text and no the end of the function.

I am using `addslashes()` and have tried various other encodings but nothing like that seems to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best solution here is to stop using `href="javascript:…` and start using [unobtrusive JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) and [progressive enhancement](http://icant.co.uk/articles/pragmatic-progressive-enhancement/).

If you do want to continue down this route, then you need to remember that you are dealing with **three** different languages and generating one from the other in a chain.

Start with the JavaScript. Then make it work with the HTML. Then make it work with the PHP.

```
javascript:playSong('Danny Elfman','Beetlejuice "Theme" (Kamei Halloween Edit)','2009-10-31-10-52-01.4521.data','28330')
```

There are no syntax errors here. You just have double quotes in a string.

```
href="javascript:playSong('Danny Elfman','Beetlejuice "Theme" (Kamei Halloween Edit)','2009-10-31-10-52-01.4521.data','28330')"
```

Now you hava nested the JavaScript in an HTML attribute which is delimited  with double quotes. This means that the double quotes in the JS are now a problem as it terminates the attribute value half way through the script.

Deal with these quotes in the usual way for HTML. Replace them with an HTML entity: `&quot;`

```
href="javascript:playSong('Danny Elfman','Beetlejuice &quot;Theme&quot; (Kamei Halloween Edit)','2009-10-31-10-52-01.4521.data','28330')"
```

Then we get to the PHP:

```
echo '<a href="javascript:playSong'."('$row[artist]','$row[title]','$row[sourcefile]')".'">';
```

Dealing with quotes inside quotes inside quotes is a pain. So don't try.

```
href="javascript:playSong('<?php echo $row[artist] ?>','<?php echo $row[title] ?>','<?php echo $row[sourcefile]; ?>')"
```

You seem to have lost an argument between examples there.

Follow the normal rules for dealing with inserting content into HTML with PHP: htmlspecialchars

```
href="javascript:playSong('<?php echo htmlspecialchars($row[artist]); ?>','<?php echo htmlspecialchars($row[title]); ?>','<?php echo htmlspecialchars($row[sourcefile]); ?>')"
```

Comment: totally agree with what you're saying, but in some projects, that you just have to maintain you still need to cope with that kind of problems.

Comment: Yes if I had known what I was doing I would have made it differently in Jquery but just trying to patch it for now.

Comment: This still needs JS-escaping (`addslashes` or `json_encode`) before the `htmlspecialchars` is applied; otherwise apostrophes, backslashes and newlines will cause problems. Note If you have a lot of code like this I'm afraid your app is going to be highly insecure, full of both JS-injections and HTML-injections. I would strongly advise moving to unobtrusive techniques to reduce the amount of nested string escaping you need to do. Also `javascript:` URLs should simply never be used; they are in every way worse than a simple `onclick`.

Comment: I do use addslashes() before anything.  I realize it's made pretty crappily but it is a app I only use for myself. I will remake it sometime most likely with jquery.

@David Dorward thanks! finally got that working.

Comment: Also htmlspecialchars() should have the ENT_QUOTES tag on correct?

Comment: You only *need* ENT_QUOTES if you are using single-quotes as the attribute value delimiter, but it's a good practice to always include anyhow.

Answer (score 1):

Escaping **ONLY** with backslash won't help you because you also need to escape them in html, try using `&#39;` for single quotes and `&#34;` for double quotes in your embedded js functions.

This should do what you need.

Sinan.

Comment: Both JS-string-literal-escaping *and* then HTML-escaping are needed when putting code in a string in JavaScript in HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Oh. You need to escape it in html. Try [htmlspecialchars](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php):

Comment: They are but it still fails... Looks ilke javascript:playSong('artist','beetlejuice \       in the link.